# In jquery:event key and mouse together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a slide of test with arrow for the next slide.
I want go to next slide also with key(arrow).
How can I this in Jquery?

Comment: can you please post code so we can be of more help? :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0xz2c8p4/    this is only with button arrow, i want supported that with key arrow. So when i click the key right arrow, it should the same function of button arrow (sorry for understanding)

Answer (score 1):

You can use e.which to find the value of the key pressed. I believe e.which returns:

37 - left arrow

38 - up arrow

39 - right arrow

40 - down arrow

Simply check for whichever number e.which returns

```
$(function(){
    $('html').keydown(function(e){
       $('#keypress_con').text(e.which);
    });
});
```

Here is a link to a JSFiddle that you can use as an example to catch arrow key press events:

http://jsfiddle.net/SLtFk/1/

Comment: I have just a clickevent and i want support that with arrowkey. ex. in button right arrow i have event with a function, i want implemented the key arrow in that function. sorry for bad english

Comment: Oh wait, are you trying to find when the arrow keys (from the keyboard) are pressed or do you have arrow buttons?

Comment: please post your html code to the question so I can understand what you mean

Comment: this is a example, i want go to right with arrow key